# What if I got an idea that has been recently published, should I invest time considering it?

Tags: publications, research-process, masters

I got an idea for my master's work but when I did some research it turned out that someone published it in 2016. Should I stick to my idea as maybe I can do some improvements or at least I can give other interpretations or raise some questions or should I leave it behind. Can you propose me some solutions?

Thank you!

Comment: _I got an idea for my master's work but [it has already been] published...Should I [develop the] idea...or should I leave it behind._ Your questions seems highly personally and doesn't seen like something we can answer. Perhaps you can rephrase? Add more context? Or ...

Comment: Have you discussed it with your advisor?

Comment: No, I do not have an advisor yet.

Comment: @HybridAlien I see. Well, it's worth discussing it with potential advisors then. The details will matter - some research ideas are much more fertile than others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to work in this small sub area, you can pursue it. You are a bit behind the frontier if work was published a few years ago and you need to get up to that frontier if you want to advance it. That will take some effort and such efforts are worth it, just to develop your mind.

But you also have new information that will help you get to the frontier quickly: the new paper and other recent work.

On the other hand, leaving everything else aside to pursue ground that you know others are already plowing, seems sub-optimal. I'd suggest pursuit, but not that exclusively. Develop a lot of ideas shallowly (and keep notes) so that you can pursue a few of them deeply.